# Zimbra server - Ubuntu - Configuration

Tags: linux, zimbra

I'm trying to setup Zimbra so that it has an automatic fallover.  The ideas is that two Zimbra servers will be running and if one fails there will be little to 0 downtime as the other will either be already routing emails to the client or start routing when the first fails.

I would have to assure that email is being sent to both servers so that there is no lose of data.  Because of this I can't have both servers added the client because everyone would end up having two copies of every email.

Is there an easy way to do this or has anyone done this before?

Comment: This does not seem like programming question to me, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Serverfault.com might be better site for configuration questions.

Answer (score 0):

warm standy not currently possible, this would have to be done at the VMware/OS layer.